# Is there any up-to-date list of hours of work needed to buy a Big Mac?

Tags: purchasing-power-partity

Is there any up-to-date list of hours of work needed to buy a Big Mac?

I have found only [up to 2018](http://www.citymayors.com/economics/big-mac-guide.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could not find any more recent Big Mac Index in terms of hours worked, and I dont think it is avaiable as wage statistics is usually reported with 1-2 year lag in many countries, but the Economist provides the Big Mac Index in USD, EUR, GBP and few other currencies up to January 2020  and it is being kept up to date with about 1 quarter lag. You can find the index *[here](https://www.economist.com/news/2020/01/15/the-big-mac-index)* and raw data for all years [here](https://github.com/TheEconomist/big-mac-data/blob/master/output-data/big-mac-2020-01-14.xls).

Based on their index you can calculate how many hours (or in this case mostly minutes) it takes in some selected countries. For example you can find hourly wages by month in the US for 2020 at the [U.S. Bureau of Labor Statistics](https://www.bls.gov/news.release/empsit.t19.htm). You will be able to do this for most rich developed countries but not for all countries around the world.

Comment: (-1) is for the answer or the person?

Comment: Note that April 2020 saw a substantial increase in average hourly pay as a side-effect of Covid-19: many higher salaried workers are working from home and being paid while many minimum-wage workers have become unemployed and are not longer in the statistics (though their short-term benefits may exceed their previous wage)

Comment: @1muflon1 McDonald's critics are commonplace these days :)

Comment: @emeryville I was asking because recently no matter what answer I make I receive 1 downvote without any constructive criticism or context or even obvious reason. I don’t know if that’s everyone’s experience with SE - until recently this have never happened to me but at this point It seems more like a downvote upon my person rather than the answer itself.

Comment: @1muflon1 I heard about a similar problem from someone who had an argument with an OP.  I assume the user filled out a complaint because SE can identify whether the downvote is specific or not. Anyway, this is very annoying.

Comment: @emeryville I also flagged the last answer this happened to for attention of moderators. To be honest I am not that concerned about the lost rep from all those (-1) downvotes but I feel this undermines the credibility of the system. Also if I hurt someone’s feeling so much to resort to this I wish I could apologize to the person because I try to treat everyone with respect but sometimes constructive criticism might be misconstrued as insult but I don’t try to hurt anyone. If someone’s holding grudge for over a week now I must have seriously unintentionally hurt them that makes me sad in itself

Comment: @1muflon1 I don’t know that even moderators can tell who up or downvoted something, but I think there is an algorithm that identifies serial downvotes of an individual that (presumably based on other votes) reverts them if it looks like it’s personal and not based on content.

Comment: @dismalscience I looked it up on SE meta after first week of the pattern and the answer was that the algorithm can only detect some overt abuse not if someone ‘automatically’ gives you downvote every day on 1-2 questions. The meta post recommended flagging it - so I guess there is some way of resolving it that way. Anyway as mentioned above it’s not about points - I wish that whoever is doing that would just approach me so I can apologize for hurting them so much that they resorted to this and then just keep everything professional and not personal

Comment: Huh, good to know. Anyway, I’m sorry that’s happening to you. It’s not good for the platform.